# Computer won't boot without a USB drive?

Tags: boot

I ran boot-repair and got [this pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14455100/)

The computer won't even let me run the BIOS without the USB I installed Ubuntu from plugged in. Interestingly enough, I formatted that USB drive right after I installed, so I don't know why it would even be a factor here. Any advice?

Comment: Just to clarify the situation more: I'm only running Ubuntu on this hard drive. Got it running once but ran into some dependency errors from mucking about. Reinstalled from Live USB, choosing the options to delete everything on the hard drive and did a default install. It ran fine all day.. I formatted the USB stick, but later on when I took the stick out, the thing wouldn't boot at all.... until I put it back in out of curiosity.

Comment: Update: tried running boot-repair from a Live USB, I got http://paste.ubuntu.com/14455395/ . Alas, it still won't boot without the USB.

Comment: I ended up reformatting, installing Windows, and then dual booting Ubuntu on another partition. My suspicion is that I placed grub2 in a weird location on the first install, and ended up misplacing it or forgetting to install a new one on the second install. Gonna leave this open on the off chance somebody takes the time to make a non-nuclear workaround for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to fool around with a similar /dev/sdb device, my problem was that the sdb was trying to "start at boot" i cant remember what i did exactly to change it back. If you can access your desktop then go into the disks program and edit the mount options and remove the "start at boot" check box. Not sure if this will help, if you cant access the desktop somehow obtain a live cd, and you can change a config file somewhere but cant remember where.

Comment: I think the sdb device trying to automount is the only reason I can start this thing up in the first place. To reiterate: the system won't start up without the USB stick plugged in.

Comment: I'm sorry not automount it was the "mount at startup" box that was checked ill edit this now.

Comment: The file that the mount options are under is, at least on my system, "/etc/fstab" you can edit this with live cd to fix the problem will come back later and "reedit" my answer when it lets me.